# Displaying stars using angular application

Tags: angular

I have a component, the requirement says the component should have stars wrapped in its own `span` tags, the number of stars to be displayed is decided by the input `totalCount`, I have to use `&#9733;` to show a star symbol as per requirement:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'movies-app',
  template: `
  <span *ngFor="let a of arr">{{"&#9733;"}}</span>
  `,
})
export class MovieComponent implements OnInit {
  arr = [];

  @Input('totalCount')
  public totalCount: number;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.arr = new Array(this.totalCount);
  }

}
```

I have a hidden test case for this program that fails with error as :

> Angular Movies: Movie component - if totalCount is 4, then 4 stars
> should be filled (★) Output (stderr): Error:
> expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
>
> Expected: "?" Received: "?"
> at /task/src/app/movie.spec.ts:72:64

If I tried `<span><ng-container *ngFor="let a of arr">{{"&#9733;"}}</ng-container></span>` the error says expected 4 span tags but got only 1 span tag.

Also I tried `<span *ngFor="let a of arr" [innerHTML]="&#9733;"></span>` this is also failing.

As the test cases are hidden, I am not able to guess correctly what is the correct solution for this.

Comment: add the unit test for this particular case

Comment: looks like an Uplers interview question, was not able to pass this case at all.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of each star wrapped in a span, your first solution will render:

```
<span>
  &#9733;
  &#9733;
  &#9733;
  &#9733;
<span>
```

Your second solution won't work because you need to pass `[innerHTML]` a string: `[innerHTML]="'&#9733;'"`

There is no need to use `{{}}` with an [HTML entity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity). I would suggest the following solution as the simplest:

```
<span *ngFor="let a of arr">&#9733;</span>
```

Comment: I tired this approach also, getting same error